# <input> element value attribute does not match control contents?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I used jQuery `clone()` to copy a `<div>`.

The code then clears any `<input>` values in the clone before inserting it back into the DOM using `element.val('')`.

However, after clearing the `<input>` values, the `value` attribute of the new element still has the copied value.

This is demonstrated in the screenshot below. The selected `<input>` element shows no text. However, you can see in the markup that the `value` attribute still has the value from the original element that was cloned (shown in the previous row).

[image]

How can the `value` attribute not match what is in the textbox?

Comment: The `value` property is not the same as the `value` attribute. The attribute is the initial default value, and it's used if you call `form.reset()`.

Comment: @Barmar: Wow, that's new to me then. For some reason, the client-side validation isn't firing when it's empty. So I thought maybe it was picking up the value attribute.